# Proving AB to be non singular given conditions on A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I need help in it.

> Question :Let A be a m cross n  matrix and B be a n cross m matrix over a real numbers with m<n . Then how to prove that AB will always be non-singular?

I can't think anything except assuming 2 general matrix but if I assume all entries of both matrix equal to 0 then I will get it a singular matrix.

So, Is question wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the question is wrong.

The thing we *can* prove is that $BA$ will always be singular, because it's an $n\times n$ matrix with rank at most $m<n$. But $AB$ might also be singular, as your example with setting all entries equal to $0$ shows.